# Binary file not holding data properly

Tags: c++, filestream, binaryfiles

Im currently trying to replace a text based file in my application with a binary one. Im just doing some early tests so the code isn't exactly safe but I'm having problems with the data. 
When trying to read out the data it gets about half way before it starts coming back with incorrect results.

Im creating the file in c++ and my client application is c#. I think the problem is in my c++ (which I haven't used very much)

Where the problem is at the moment is I have a vector of a struct that is called DoubleVector3 which consists of 3 doubles

```
struct DoubleVector3 {
    double x, y, z;
    DoubleVector3(std::string line);
};
```

Im currently writing the variables individually to the file

```
void ObjElement::WriteToFile(std::string file) {

    std::ofstream fileStream;
    fileStream.open(file); //, ios::out | ios::binary);

    // ^^problem was this line. it should be 
    // fileStream.open(file, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

    fileStream << this->name << '\0';
    fileStream << this->materialName << '\0';

    int size = this->vertices.size();

    fileStream.write((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
    //i have another int written here

    for (int i=0; i<this->vertices.size(); i++) {
        fileStream.write((char*)&this->vertices[i].x, 8);
        fileStream.write((char*)&this->vertices[i].y, 8);
        fileStream.write((char*)&this->vertices[i].z, 8);
    }

    fileStream.close();
}
```

When I read the file in c# the first 6 sets of 3 doubles are all correct but then I start getting 0s and minus infinities

Am I doing anything obviously wrong in my WriteToFile code?

I have the file uploaded on mega if anyone needs to look at it 
https://mega.co.nz/#!XEpHTSYR!87ihtCfnGXJJNn13iE6GIpeRhlhbabQHFfN88kr_BAk

(im writing the name and material in first then the number of vertices before the actual list of vertices)
Small side question - Should I delimit these doubles or just add them in one after the other?

Comment: Is the `ios::binary` actually commented out in your real code too? If so, why? And BTW, why `8` instead of `sizeof(vertices[i].x)`?

Comment: it is commented out because i was getting an error from it and it seemed to working fine without it. I have iostream and fstream included but it wasn't recognising out or binary.

Comment: I did originally have sizeof, was just trying different things and hadnt changed it back from 8

Comment: It's not `ios::binary`, it's `ios_base::binary`. Without it, a `0x0D` is inserted before each `0x0A`.

Comment: That was the problem alright, Thanks! wanna change that to an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store binary data in a stream, you must add `std::ios_base::binary` to the stream's flags when opening it. Without this, the stream is opened in text mode and line-ending conversions can happen.

On Windows, line-ending conversions mean inserting a byte `0x0D` (ASCII for carriage-return) before each `0x0A` byte (ASCII for line-feed). Needless to say, this corrupts binary data.